# Current Json.NET version and NuGet

Tags: json.net, nuget

I'm having problems installing the latest version of Json.NET from nuget.org.  If I create a new VS project and run:

Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

It pulls down version 5.0.8, but the splash page is for 6.0.5.  No other versions seem to be available.  This is causing problems for our build process.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any package sources besides nuget.org added in settings?

Comment: Which version of .net is your project?